# Prove that $\mathbb {D}_4 $ is isomorphic with $\mathbb {Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_2 \times\mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups

I tried comparing characteristics between the Dihedral group and the $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ group, but I need help to be able to define the function and be able to carry out the corresponding demonstration. Thank you

Comment: I take it $\mathbb{D}_4$ is the dihedral group of order $8$? (No, it’s not isomorphic to that; hint: is $(\mathbb{Z}_2)^3$ abelian? Is $\mathbb{D}_4$ abelian?

Comment: No element of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2  \times \mathbb Z_2 $ has order $4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're not isomorphic.

The [dihedral group $D_{4}$ of eight elements](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/D4.html) has an element of order four; in particular, the rotation of the square by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ about the origin will suffice. No element of [$\Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2\times \Bbb Z_2$](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/1/C2%5E3.html) has order four, since, as can be computed readily, each nontrivial element has order two. Isomorphisms preserve orders of elements.

Answer (score 1):

$D_8$ is not abelian, but $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_2$ is.